# How to retrieve the first 5 items in the stack (Higher Performance)

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, stack

I was recently asked this interview question:

**How to retrieve the first 5 items in the stack ?**

Stack as you know is Last In First Out

Interviewer asked for algorithm/pseudocode with high performance for a stack with only 2 operations, Pop() and Push().

**My trivial answer:**

```
Stack S2;
foreach (item in stack S1)
{
  object item = S1.Pop();
  S2.push(item)
}

for (int i=0 ; i<5 ; i++)
 Printf(S2.Pop());
```

He told me that we have another solution with higher performance but I cannot find one.

Comment: There is something missing here. Does the stack support `empty()` as well? And your algorithm is in `O(n)`, which is as good as it gets to access the most remote element in a list/stack. I'd wager that the interviewer wanted you to tell him that your solution is asymptotically optimal, and tell him why.

Comment: @HotLicks Stack is LIFO Last In First Out so you will get the first 5 items at the bottom of the stack

Comment: Question is too vague: Does "first" mean "top" or "bottom"?  What is done with the values?  What does the state of the stack need to be when done?

Comment: If the intent is to retrieve the bottom two elements, with no access to the stack depth other than "empty", then pop the elements into a 5-element array, with an incrementing index modulo 5.  One can then tell which element is the first by looking at the index when the stack goes empty.

Comment: But it's a dumb question -- who would use a stack with no "peek" capability if they needed to do this?  "Peek" adds no overhead.

Comment: @HotLicks: This data structure is currently called a "ring buffer".

Comment: thabet, what I think the instructor was suggesting was that you pop the entire stack, push it onto another stack and then pop the first 5 elements.  This means you perform 2*n + 5 operations.  If you save the most recent 5 items in an array as other suggest, you can do this in n operations (assuming you don't save the original stack).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to have been a communication issue.  To get the first five elements that were put onto the stack then I would do the following:

```
input: Stack S1;
Stack S2;
Stack S3;
Object[5] elementArray;
int elementIndex = 0;

foreach (item in Stack S1)
{
  elementArray[elementIndex] = item;
  elementIndex = ++elementIndex % 5 // modulus operation.
  S2.push(item); // only needed to restore S1 to its' original state.
}

elementIndex = ++elementIndex % 5 // advance to the 5th element from the bottom.

for (int index = 0; index < 5; ++index)
{
  S3.push(elementArray[elementIndex]);
  elementIndex = ++elementIndex % 5
}

foreach (item in Stack S2)
{
  S1.push(item);
}
```

End Result:

1. S1 is unchanged.
2. S2 is empty.
3. S3 contains the first five elements (I think of these as the bottom 5 elements) from stack S1 in inverse order.

Comment: you retrieved here the Last(top) 5 items and the question that we need first(bottom) 5 items from stack .

Answer (score 1):

If Push() and Pop() are assumed expensive, you can save 5 of each by keeping the last 5 items in an array. If the rest of the stack can be discarded, you can save a lot more.

```
#ifdef NEED_REST_OF_STACK
Stack newstack;
#endif

object[] cache=new object[5];
object tmp;
int i=0;

while (tmp=originalstack.Pop()) {
  cache[i%5]=tmp;
#ifdef NEED_REST_OF_STACK
  if (i>4) newstack.Push(cache[(i-1)%5]); //This assumes a%b>=0 in this language
#endif
  i++;
}

#ifdef REST_OF_STACK_MUST_BE_IN_ORIGINAL_ORDER
  //Revert stack back
  while (tmp=newstack.Pop()) originalstack.Push(tmp);
#else
  originalstack=newstack;
#endif
```

Stack is in originalstack, result is in cache.

Answer (score 0):

reserve a new assist-stack with size 5 for original-stack, and maintain the bottom 5 objects in assist-stack when pushing and poping object to/from original-stack.

```
Stack OriS;
Stack AsiS;     #stack size is 5


#push

if(AsiS.size() <5) AsiS.push(obj);
OriS.push(obj);

#pop

if(OriS.size() <= 5) AsiS.pop();
OriS.pop();
```

the bottom 5 elements is stored in asisst-stack.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the question assumed big constant overhead of calling Pop (RPC over a slow unreliable network or whatever you can think of). In this case you could:

- Implement the stack as an array with a read/write pointer.
- Define Pop with a parameter: Pop(int depth). Calling Pop(5) would advance the pointer by 5 positions and bring a chunk of 5 array entries at once.